# Access List created in GlWidget in Mainwindow to write a file

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I am a novice in programming. Probably, this question is very simple to answer. I am generating a list for points in `glwidget.cpp`:

```
void GLWidget::setPoint(double px, double py, double pz)
{
          pc[0] = px;
          pc[1] = py;
          pc[2] = pz;
         pointList.append(pc[0]);
         pointList.append(pc[1]);
         pointList.append(pc[2]);
}
void GLWidget::plotPoint()
{
        glPointSize(7.0);
        glColor3f (0, 0, 0);
        for (int i=0; i<pointList.count()-2; i=i+3)
        {
          glBegin(GL_POINTS);
          glVertex3f(pointList.at(i), pointList.at(i+1), pointList.at(i+2));
          glEnd();
        }
        update();
}
```

The list is defined in `glwidget.h`:

```
class GLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GLWidget();

    QList<double> pointList;
}
```

and I am trying to write a file in the `mainwindow.cpp`:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSave_triggered()
{
    QFile file(filePath);
    if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)) {
    QMessageBox::warning(this,"..","file not open");
    return;
  }
    QTextStream out(&file);

    out << "// point:\n";
    for (int i=0; i<pointList.count()-2; i=i+3)
    {
    out << pointList;
    }
}
```

It seems that `mainwindow.cpp` does not see the list as I am getting an error message that `pointList` is not declared. How to fix it?

Comment: pointList is an attribute of the GLWidget class, so you want to use pointList you must do it by mediating a GLWidget object. Have you created any GLWidget class objects in MainWindow?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for reply. No, because I do not understand how to make it.

Comment: The most likely to happen is that you have little knowledge of OOP, I recommend that you review the books, take a course, etc. SO is not a service of learning and tutoring, we are dedicated to solving specific problems, but if the OP does not have the basic knowledge it will be difficult to do so. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I read about OOP, just I am confused how to combine it with QList and QT. I solved the problem by using signal-slot mechanism. It works, but I am not sure if it is the optimal way for QList transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it will help to other novices and I am not sure if it is the best solution. At least it works without any problems.

connection in `mainwindow.cpp`:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(sendPoint(QList<double>)),
                 ui->openGLWidget, SLOT(getPoint(QList<double>)));
```

emit signal:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_add_clicked()
{
    ...
     emit sendPoint(QList<double> (pointList));
}
```

getting in slot:

```
void GLWidget::getPoint(QList<double> (pointList))
{
    pointGList = pointList;
}
```